# Check whether a file exists

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Write a script “test.sh”, the script will test whether a file named “goodbye” exists in the current directory or not, and print “I am here” if the file is in current directory.

I was given this question in a "word document" with no prior explanation, that is the question I was given, I think I am supposed to write a script using test.sh to see if the file goodbye is in the current directory and if it is there it should print "I am here" if the file is there. But I'm not sure how to use test.sh.

The code I did, still unsure:

```
cisco@ubuntu:~$ > goodbye
if [ -f goodbye ]; then
echo "I am here"
fi
```

Comment: Which part _can_ you do? It's homework so your teacher/lecturer will have given you some instruction. Please [edit] your question to show what you have got so far, and explain what you think it's doing. Include error messages (if any). You may also want to pass your code through https://shellcheck.net to pick out syntax issues

Comment: Can you use an editor? Can you echo `I am here` back to the terminal? What do you want to test about the file `goodbye`? Its name? Its size? Whether it not it exists? Be precise.

Comment: If you're going to reply, please simply [update your question to give more detail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/693985/edit). Pretend you wrote it with more detail in the first place - there's an edit history so it's easy enough to see how the question has developed.

Comment: I think you're using a different account to try and edit your question. I've added my vote to approve your change, but in order to vote on answers and accept a useful one you'll need to [ask the moderators to merge your two accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: You're supposed to write a script _named_ `test.sh`, that's just an example name for your script, not something that already exists.

Comment: Note that the `-f` test is a file type test that tests whether the given name is a regular file or not. If you want to test for existence, use `-e`.

Comment: I would consider paying attention to the lecture during the class. That should make fulfilling the assignment trivial.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not as easy as it may seem, as you need to define first what you mean by *file* and by *exist*.

- is a directory, a fifo, a symlink, a device... a *file*. The `-f` operator of the `[` utility only returns true for *regular files* or symlinks which can be determined to eventually resolve to a *regular file* and excludes all of the above.
- is it enough for a directory entry by that name to be found in the directory to claim its existence, or do we have to be able to `lstat()` the file (check that the path resolves to an actual file) or to `stat()` (check that the path resolve to an actual path after symlink resolution).

Then, what should happen if the current directory is not readable or is not searchable? Should we treat that as an error and abort rather than potentially incorrectly claiming that the file doesn't exist?

```
if [ -f file ]; then
  echo I am here
fi
```

Would output "I am here" if `file` can be successfully identified as a regular file after symlink resolution, and would not if `file` didn't exist or the file was not a regular one (determined after symlink resolution), or the type of the file could not be determined for one reason or another. Search access to the current working directory is necessary, but not read access.

```
if [ -e file ]; then
  echo I am here
fi
```

Same except the file can be of any type. Like above, "I am here" would not be output if `file` is a symlink which we can not resolve (because the link is broken or points to an area the user doesn't have access).

```
if [ -e file ] || [ -L file ]; then
  echo I am here
fi
```

Same, but also covers the case where `file` is a broken symlink.

It could give you a false negative if the current working directory is not searchable. This kind of thing can happen if the permissions of the directory have changed since you `cd`'ed into it, or the process credentials have changed since.

Using:

```
if ls -d file > /dev/null; then
  echo I am here
fi
```

Would do the same `[ -e file ] || [ -L file ]` and also give an error explaining why the file can't be found.

In the `zsh` shell, you can also use the `$ERRNO` special variable to identify the reason.

If you don't have search access to the current directory, but have read access to it and know its full path, you can still check whether there's an entry in it for a `file` file, with something like (assuming a POSIX shell such as bash):

```
set -- "$PWD"/[f]ile
case $1 in
  (*/file) echo "I am here"
esac
```

(note that there can be corner cases where `$PWD` could not match the path of the current working directory which could give you false positives).

See [this answer of mine to a similar Q&A on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40046642) for more information.

Answer (score -4):

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -f goodbye ] && echo "I am here"
```

Comment: Adding comments or explanation would be useful to help the person asking the question to understand your code, and to learn from it. Otherwise all you've done is given them an answer to a piece of coursework that they may not be able to justify if challenged, and for the next one they will be no further along in their education.